# How to set listener queue name from environment variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, listener, jobs

I just noticed that some of my listeners do not use the queue I expected them to use. Our team upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.5 a few weeks back, and I guess this is when the problem started happening. There hasn't been much load on the system, so I only discovered it by accident.

Anyway. I used to set the queue name on the listener through a queue method, like so:

```
public function queue(QueueManager $handler, $method, $arguments): void
{
    $handler->connection()->push($method, $arguments, Queue::getNotificationQueue());
}
```

This approach is not working anymore, so a default queue ends up handling the job instead of the expected notification queue.

So I looked at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#queued-event-listeners, which states that the name should be set on a queue property on the listener. My problem is that I have the queue name in an environment variable, so I cannot just set it directly as a property, as shown in the documentation and it does not work to set it on the constructor, like so:

```
protected $queue;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->queue = Queue::getNotificationQueue();
}
```

Does anyone here have an idea of how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for SQS queues the `$queue` property acts a bit weird because it doesn't seem to refer to queues defined in `queue.php`, but it expects a full queue url, so even the example in the documentation seems off.

But for dynamic queue names on queued event listeners that for example changes depending on environment, making a custom `SqsConnector` and `SqsQueue` will be one way to solve your issue.

Here is an example of implementation.

ACMEEventListener.php

```
class ACMEEventListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(Event $event): void
    {
        // I'm going to a custom queue
    }

    public static function getQueue(): string
    {
        return 'https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<account id>/<queue name>';
    }
}
```

CustomSqsConnector.php

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SqsConnector;
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;

class CustomSqsConnector extends SqsConnector
{
    public function connect(array $config)
    {
        $sqs = new SqsClient($config);

        return new CustomSqsQueue($sqs, $config['queue']);
    }
}
```

CustomSqsQueue.php

```
class CustomSqsQueue extends \Illuminate\Queue\SqsQueue
{

    public function push($job, $data = '', $queue = null)
    {
        if ($job instanceof CallQueuedListener && method_exists($job->class, 'getQueue')) {
            $queue = $job->class::getQueue();
        }

        return $this->pushRaw($this->createPayload($job, $data), $queue);
    }
}
```

CustomSqsQueueServiceProvider.php

```
class CustomSqsQueueServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->booted(function () {
            $this->app['queue']->extend('custom_sqs', function () {
                return new CustomSqsConnector;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And then in your `queue.php`, your default SQS connection driver from `sqs` to `custom_sqs`

Comment: Makes sense. I will attempt this solution and get back to you soon. Thanks.

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: @mewm the custom queue should put in the handle?

Comment: need some help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727992/laravel-set-queue-delay-dynamically-for-event-listener